# python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully - requirements.txt not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm attempting to deploy my code to elastic beanstalk. Based on the logs, the requirements.txt file is located the the required packages are installed. But, at some point during the deployment process, something happens and this error gets thrown in the eb-engine.log file as a result of the requirements.txt file not being found.

```
 2023/09/30 18:24:19.351277 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [InstallDependency]. Stop running the command. Error: fail to install dependencies with requirements.txt file with error Command /bin/sh -c /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-a4Qt9rti/awsebcli_b390asd44f43fadfa6e9f161178cc/setup.py", line 22, in <module>
          with open("requirements.txt") as req:
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: Can you please cross check if requirements.txt file is present in the bundle? Or there is any typo in the file name?

Comment: It was an no typo. Answer provided below. thanks for your response though :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that awsebcli was listed as a requirement